# Looping to enter values into Java Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

i am trying to insert values into a hashmap. I have it in a loop as the values are being retrieved from a list of strings. The code is as follows:

```
HashMap<String, String> resultHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

//add the top document id back to the resultHashMap
resultHashMap.put("entryObject", dsStepParam.getValue());

for(String res : results) 
{
    log.info(res);
    resultHashMap.put("dataObject", res);
}
```

The hashMap (after this loop should contain the following:

```
{"entryObject":"500386787",
"dataObject":"500386883;500901929",
"dataObject":"500386906;500901969",
"dataObject":"500386787;500901666",
"dataObject":"500386784;500901654",
"dataObject":"500386762;500901599"}
```

however the actual contents are:

```
{"entryObject":"500386787",
"dataObject":"500386762;500901599"}
```

As you can see it only stores the entryObject and the last dataObject.
How can I make it store all the values in the hashMap?

Comment: Think about another structure of your data, HashMap stores one value per unique key

Comment: You should use Integer as key, if possible. It's better for performance and will use less memory. No point in creating constants like dataObject-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It only stores the last entry because duplicate keys are not allowed in a hashmap. To store all elements you could do something like this

```
int count = 0;
for(String res : results) 
{
    log.info(res);
    resultHashMap.put("dataObject-"+count, res);
    count++;
}
```

Thus you'd get something like this

```
{"entryObject":"500386787",
"dataObject-1":"500386883;500901929",
"dataObject-2":"500386906;500901969",
"dataObject-3":"500386787;500901666",
"dataObject-4":"500386784;500901654",
"dataObject-5":"500386762;500901599"}
```

Comment: So despite the key/value pair being unique, the key in itself has to be unique??

Comment: Yes. There is a MultiMap in Google's common collections lib I believe that allows you to have what you want.

Comment: In Oracle's implementation of the Map, yes, the key has to be unique.

Comment: Ok that puts a dent into my plan!! Thanks for your quick replies and your help.

Comment: Dont worry this will be the answer I accept however it wont let me do it for another 7 minutes :P

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to store all values in the hashMap you need to allow duplicates in the map.  For this to happen, you'd need to use Google's version of Multimap, which can be found [here](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Answer (score 1):

The keys in hashMap are unique so you are seeing the last entry for the duplicate keys inserts. If you want to store multiple items associated to one key then you can make use MultiMap i.e a map that holds a collection of values against each key. Couple of good multimap implementations are available:

- [Apache MultiMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html)
- [Guava MultiMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)